# Como mostrar de una fecha solo el día, mes y año

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs, reactjs, postgresql

Verán, tengo para empezar una tabla Cliente. En esa tabla tengo una variable fecha, en la cual se muestra la fecha en la que registramos en la BBDD ese cliente:

```
create table cliente(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  dni integer,
  fecha_registro date
);

insert into cliente (nombre, dni, fecha_registro) values('Paco Monales',39011210,'2010-02-25');
insert into cliente (nombre, dni, fecha_registro) values('Laura Gimenez',90518271,'2018-04-17');
```

La cosa es que se tiene que mostrar todos los clientes en una lista, pero algo raro pasa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A pesar de que yo solo puse el año, mes y día tambien se muestra la hora, y para colmo de una forma muy confusa.
Para colocar la lista de clientes uso este código:

```
  {clienteData.map((cliente, i) => {
    return (
      <ul className="lista-profe" key={i}>
        <h2>{cliente.nombre}</h2>
        <h4>NIF: {nif(cliente.dni)}</h4>
        <h4>Fecha de Registro: {cliente.fecha_registro}</h4>
      </ul>
    );
  })}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de que `cliente.fecha_registro` se muestre como año-mes-dia sin más?

Comment: Agregaron que tu pregunta ya tenia respuesta, pudiste resolverlo ?

Comment: Pues si, encontré una solución a mi problema.